# Avoiding loading onCreateView() in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have added two fragments in my application, When I move to second fragment from first fragment its working fine.

But, now when I navigating back to my first fragment from second fragment, I don't want to load onCreateView() method of my first fragment.

How can I avoid calling onCreateView() of first fragment second time while returning from second fragment ?
How can I do it ?

Comment: Paste the code of 'When you go from `Fragment A` to `Fragment B`.

Comment: First fragment sholud be remain its loaded state, It should not load the data again which is happening in onCreateView() of first fragment. Thats Why I want to avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

When you coming back from second fragment to first fragment your view will be recreate its the life cycle of fragment and it should be always call.

To avoid the call for data in `onCreateView()` method you can put a check before making call for data is the data is already available or not.

As your fragment is already in stack so `onCreate()` will not get call in this case so take a boolean flag (isDataLoaded) which is false in `onCreate()` method and when you get the data through making call from onCreateView() you can make it true. and put a check on `onCreateView()` before making call for new data isDataLoaded is false then make the call else it will use the old data.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are creating a new Fragment when you go back. Instead, you should keep a reference to the fragment you are going back to.